# Can this $2\times 2$ system of 1st-order ODEs, one linear and one non-linear, be solved in closed form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working with the following family of 1st-order ODE systems:

$$\begin{array}{l}{x_t}^\prime  = A{x_t} - B{y_t}^n\\{y_t}^\prime  = {g_t} - {x_{t,}}\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabe
% aacaWG4bWaaSbaaSqaaiaadshaaeqaaOWaaWbaaSqabeaakiadacUH
% YaIOaaGaeyypa0JaamyqaiaadIhadaWgaaWcbaGaamiDaaqabaGccq
% GHsislcaWGcbGaamyEamaaBaaaleaacaWG0baabeaakmaaCaaaleqa
% baGaamOBaaaaaOqaaiaadMhadaWgaaWcbaGaamiDaaqabaGcdaahaa
% WcbeqaaOGamai4gkdiIcaacqGH9aqpcaWGNbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadsha
% aeqaaOGaeyOeI0IaamiEamaaBaaaleaacaWG0bGaaiilaaqabaaaaa
% a!5291!
$$

where $A
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% yqaaaa!38D7!
$ and $B
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% Oqaaaa!38D8!
$
are positive constants, $n \ge 1,
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% OBaiabgwMiZkaaigdacaGGSaaaaa!3C35!
$
and ${g_t}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% 4zamaaBaaaleaacaWG0baabeaaaaa!3A22!
$
is an exogenous forcing term. When $n = 1
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% OBaiabg2da9iaaigdaaaa!3AC5!
$
this is a linear system and can be solved in closed form either directly or by integrating ${y_{t,}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% yEamaaBaaaleaacaWG0bGaaiilaaqabaaaaa!3AE4!
$
substituting into the first equation, differentiating again to get a 2nd-order linear equation, and etc.

I am now interested in whether there's a closed-form solution for $n = 2.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% OBaiabg2da9iaaikdacaGGUaaaaa!3B78!
$
The first equation is then akin to the Bernoulli DE, but this observation doesn't seem to help. I again tried substituting ${y_t}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbcvPDwzYbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0x
% e9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKk
% Fr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbiqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam
% yEamaaBaaaleaacaWG0baabeaaaaa!3A34!
$
into the first equation and differentiating, but didn't get anywhere.

I would be grateful for any advice/suggestions about whether this system is solvable in closed form and if so how, or otherwise what one can say about it.

Thank you,

-Alan